# Django: TypeError using manage.py [answered, syntax error]

Tags: django, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.7, manage.py, django-2.1

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, python3.7, and django2.1

Currently on just step 2 on Mozilla's django tutorial : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website

Checked my code multiple times and it's identical to Mozilla's code.

When I try to run `python3.7 manage.py runmigrations` or `python3.7 manage.py runserver` I get:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'list'
```

I've quadruple checked to make sure that my code is identical to the guides.

Please comment if it'd be helpful for me to post anymore of my code however.

**locallibrary/locallibrary/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/')),
]

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Catalog/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from catalog import views

urlpatterns = [

]
```

**Here is my traceback:**

https://pastebin.com/2CzdtWzK

Please scroll all the way down to the 'raw paste data'

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback...

Comment: I believe this row is wrong `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` and should be wrapped with `[` and `]`: `urlpatterns += [static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)]`. However, I'm not near a computer and unfortunately can't test myself.

Comment: @Johan: the error is about an *unary* `+`, so it means Python interprets it as if there is no left hand side.

Comment: The files does not seem to match, please remove the "byte code" files (so the `.pyc`).

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem, I didn't know that. Could it be the indentation in the first `urlpatterns`, and when the first append appears 5 rows later it's not in the same scope? It would of course be better with the full traceback, until then it's a guessing game.

Comment: Added the full trackback using the pastebin link. Please scroll down to the bottom to see the "raw paste data". The main body of text is edited by pastebin. Thank you!

Comment: @KyleI is the indentation on the first occurrence on `urlpatterns` a typo that's only in this question or is it also in your code? If not you could remove it to be on the same level as the reayof the code

Comment: @Johan that typo was only in this question but not in my code, I fixed it now. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Johan just for clarification I still get the error message. Any more ideas would be appreciated

Comment: The traceback doesn't match the code you have posted. Specifically it says the error happens on line 35 of your `urls.py` - there are far fewer than 35 lines in what you have posted. The issue is almost certainly that you have no left-hand side for a `+` operation somewhere in the code.

Comment: One possible cause for this kind of error is if you mix up "+=" with "=+" - so please check your line 34 if it is the same as posted here.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in my urls.py. I used =+ instead of +=. Thanks @ger.s.brett!